# How to use websocket client in laravel backend

Tags: laravel, websocket

I have one api for stock trade.

**this is the url for websocket communication with api server.**
https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/websocket/

I've read about websocket for laravel, but almost are the content about sending socket request from client to server.
If then, in my case, I have to turn on browser all day long to get live market quote.
I want to make it possible to get live market data without turn on browser.
Till my understanding is, in node.js, using socket.io client, it is possible to send websocket request from server to socket server.
But in laravel, I could not find way.
If anyone has experience, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `live market data without turning on browser`? Do you want to implement push notification?

Comment: No. please check my document url. I need live market quote from websocket server. and but if i implement it in client side, that is browser, i have to turn browser allday.

Comment: Thanks john. I have another question. Where can i run socket client in laravel?

Comment: Your question is so confusing. What do you mean by "I want to make it possible to get live market data without turn on browser"?  And why do you  even want to open a socket server from your laravel app to outside? It could be achieve by doing a cron job request every minute or so since you don't need to update it to front-end.